# Batch script: update database with new sql files

Tags: mysql, batch-file

So I am trying to create a batch file which I can execute in order to update multiple databases with sql files. I already created a first part which is executing the sql files in all the databases. It is not very elaborate but it does the job. My problem is that all the files are always executed.

What I would like to have is a check between the execution date/time of the batch script and the last modified date/time of every sql scripts. Thanks to this, I can only execute the sql scripts which were modified/created after the execution of the batch script. I tried quite hard but didn't manage to script this functionality. I'm not really good with batch scripts ^^

Thanks !

**The Script**

```
@echo off 

set "mySQLexe=C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysql.exe"
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (databases.txt) do ( 
  for %%G in (*.sql) do ( 
      %mySQLexe% -hlocalhost -uroot %%A < %%G 
  )
) 
REM Save execution of batch file 
@echo %date% > executiontime.txt
@echo %time% >> executiontime.txt
```

Comment: Show your existing script. This isn't making any sense to me.

Comment: `@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (databases.txt) do (

 for %%G in (*.sql) do (

  
  C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysql.exe -hlocalhost -uroot %%a < %%G
 )
)

REM Save execution of batch file
@echo %date% > executiontime.txt 
@echo %time% >> executiontime.txt `

In the databases file there is a list of all the databases I want to execute the sql files on.
Now before I execute these sql files, I want to check before if there modified date is more recent than the execution time of the batch script in order to apply only the sql files that weren't executed yet.

Comment: Sorry I don't find the option for line breaks for the code

Comment: It is easiest to just edit your existing post and add it in there. I've done that for you and made a few little tweaks too.

Comment: Date comparisons are a nightmare in batch because you have to treat them all as strings.  You'd have to extract and compare the year, month, day, hour, and minute individually.  I would consider using Powershell instead, although someone here might give you an inline vbscript that runs like it was a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "mySQLexe=C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysql.exe"
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (databases.txt) do ( 
  for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b *.sql') do ( 
    Call :FileModTime "%%G" sTime
    Call :FileModTime "%%~dpf0" bTime
    if  !sTime! GTR !bTime! (
      echo %mySQLexe% -hlocalhost -uroot %%A < %%G 
    )  
  )
) 
exit /b 

:FileModTime  File  [TimeVar]
:: Created by dbenham from dostips    ::
:: Converts current time to epox time ::
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in ("%~1") do set "file=%%~fF"
set "time="
for /f "skip=1 delims=,. tokens=2" %%A in (
  'wmic datafile where "name='%file:\=\\%'" get lastModified /format:csv 2^>nul'
) do set "ts=%%A"
set "ts=%ts%"
if defined ts (
  set /a "yy=10000%ts:~0,4% %% 10000, mm=100%ts:~4,2% %% 100, dd=100%ts:~6,2% %% 100"
  set /a "dd=dd-2472663+1461*(yy+4800+(mm-14)/12)/4+367*(mm-2-(mm-14)/12*12)/12-3*((yy+4900+(mm-14)/12)/100)/4"
  set /a "ss=(((1%ts:~8,2%*60)+1%ts:~10,2%)*60)+1%ts:~12,2%-366100-%ts:~21,1%((1%ts:~22,3%*60)-60000)"
  set /a "ts=ss+dd*86400"
)
endlocal & if "%~2" neq "" (set "%~2=%ts%") else echo(%ts%
```

Remove the echo once you have tested it and made sure it is working.